# Como trocar campo null para não retornar nada?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, null

Em uma *query* tem muitos campos sem ser preenchido, gostaria de trocar o `null` que está sendo impresso para que não apareça nada na impressão.

Comment: Bem vinda ao SoPT. Poste sua query para que possamos ajudar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a função [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```
COALESCE(coluna, '')
```

O resultado desta função é o primeiro dos dois argumentos que não seja nulo, portanto se o primeiro não for, pega o valor da coluna, caso contrário pega a *string* vazia. Isto pode ser usado em qualquer parte da consulta.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT nome, COALESCE(endereco, '') AS endereco FROM tabela
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Coalesce.sql).

Comment: [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) da o mesmo resultado correto?

Comment: @ViniciosYals no MySQL sim.

Comment: Sim, no PostgreSQL também funciona.